# $[\log_2(n)] \cdot [ \log_5(n)] < \sqrt{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I would like to prove that there is a certain $n_0$ such that for all $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n' > n_0$ we have : 
$$[\log_2(n)] \cdot [\log_5(n)] < \sqrt{n}$$

Yet I don't know how to proceed, yet I've notice that for $n = 10^{\alpha}$ we have : 
$\log_2(n) < 4\alpha$ and : $\log_5(n) < 2\alpha$ so : $[\log_2(n)] \cdot [\log_5(n)] < 8 \alpha ^2$
And we clearly have : $8 \alpha ^2 < 10^{\alpha /2}$ for all $\alpha > 10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is
$$
\log_2(n)\log_5(n)<\sqrt{n}\Leftrightarrow a_n:=\frac{\log_2(n)\log_5(n)}{\sqrt{n}}<1.
$$
It is equivalent to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n<1$. Consider the substitution $n=e^m$ and we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log_2(n)\log_5(n)}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\log_2(e^m)\log_5(e^m)}{\sqrt{e^m}}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\log_2(e)\log_5(e)m^2e^{-m/2}.
$$
Now it is easy to see that the limes is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=x^4$, where $x\geq1$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\ln^2x^4\leq(\ln2\ln5)x^2$$ or
$$\ln{x}\leq\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\ln2\ln5}x$$ or $f(x)\geq0$, where
$$f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\ln2\ln5}x}-x.$$
Now, $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\ln2\ln5}e^{\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\ln2\ln5}x}-1$$ and the rest for you.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to note that $n=100$ satisfies your inequality because $\log_2(100)+\log_5(100)\approx 9.5$.  Then note that $\frac d{dn}(\sqrt n-\log_2n-\log_5n=\frac 1{2\sqrt n}-\frac 1n(\frac 1{\log 2}+\frac 1{\log 5}) \gt 0$ for $n \gt 100$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is equivalent to the problem of finding a root of the function
$f(n)=\log _2(n) \log _5(n)-\sqrt{n}$

We have $f'(n)=\dfrac{2 \log (n)}{n \log (2) \log (5)}-\dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$

We can use the Newton method defining $n_0=1000$ and $n_k=n_{k-1}-\dfrac{f(n_{k-1})}{f'(n_{k-1})}$

after $5$ iterations we get
$$n_1=4253.57,n_2=3617.15,n_3=3625.29,n_4=3625.29,n_5=3625.29$$
Thus for $n>3626$ we have $\log _2(n) \log _5(n)<\sqrt{n}$.